# rails 404 error in subfolders in public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-crawler

it looks for me that crawlers try to resolve the index of all public folder subfolders like "/images/foo", which makes a 404 error. Should I do something or is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

In your `robots.txt`

```
Disallow: /images/foo
```

Try to keep the crawlers away from anything they don't need in order to make them focus on the things you do need.

Comment: and if images inside of foo? /images/foo/bar.png ?

Comment: No just block out the entire folder with /images/ . 99% of the time, you won't need crawlers to see or access this folder.